# generate all minute of a date in gmt and get their local value

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, dst

I'm starting to believe what I'm after is simply impossible with postgresql:

I want every GMT's minutes of a given date, and get their local version too, in the same table, as `timestamp without time zone`.

So far I'm able to get the GMT and some totally wrong offset. (I can't change the `SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris'` that'll put `+1h` every time I try to inject a time zone)

```
CREATE TABLE to_do ("id" int, "tz_lib" varchar(16));
CREATE TABLE date_needed ("date_lib" date);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8fcca/2)

**Query 3**:

```
insert into t1(id,tz_lib,date_gmt, date_local)
select 
  id,
  tz_lib,
  date_lib + (seq ||'minute')::interval AS date_gmt, 
  (date_lib + (seq ||'minute')::interval) at time zone tz_lib AS date_local
from  date_needed
cross join to_do
cross join generate_series(0,1439) AS seq
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8fcca/2/3)**:

```
| id |           tz_lib |             date_gmt |           date_local |
|----|------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  1 | Pacific/Auckland | 2018-01-15T00:00:00Z | 2018-01-14T12:00:00Z |
|  2 |     Europe/Paris | 2018-01-15T00:00:00Z | 2018-01-15T00:00:00Z |
|  3 |   Asia/Hong_Kong | 2018-01-15T00:00:00Z | 2018-01-14T17:00:00Z |
|  1 | Pacific/Auckland | 2018-01-15T00:01:00Z | 2018-01-14T12:01:00Z |
|  2 |     Europe/Paris | 2018-01-15T00:01:00Z | 2018-01-15T00:01:00Z |
|  3 |   Asia/Hong_Kong | 2018-01-15T00:01:00Z | 2018-01-14T17:01:00Z |
|  1 | Pacific/Auckland | 2018-01-15T00:02:00Z | 2018-01-14T12:02:00Z |
|  2 |     Europe/Paris | 2018-01-15T00:02:00Z | 2018-01-15T00:02:00Z |
|  3 |   Asia/Hong_Kong | 2018-01-15T00:02:00Z | 2018-01-14T17:02:00Z |
|  1 | Pacific/Auckland | 2018-01-15T00:03:00Z | 2018-01-14T12:03:00Z |
```

---

Careful with answer using `INTERVAL` as they are not DST aware and will be wrong for half the year (sadly...)

---

---

## Good result, bad method:

For now the only way I found to get the excepted result is to change the server timezone to GMT and force cast the date_local :

But **I can't use this solution** for my case...

**Query 1**:

```
SET TIME ZONE 'GMT'

insert into t1(id,tz_lib,date_gmt, date_local)
select 
  id,
  tz_lib,
  date_lib + (seq ||'minute')::interval AS date_gmt, 
  (date_lib + (seq ||'minute')::interval)::timestamptz at time zone tz_lib AS date_local
from  date_needed
cross join to_do
cross join generate_series(0,1439) AS seq
```

**Results (& Expected one)**:

```
| id |           tz_lib |             date_gmt |           date_local |
|----|------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  1 | Pacific/Auckland | 2018-01-15T00:00:00Z | 2018-01-15T13:00:00Z |
|  2 |     Europe/Paris | 2018-01-15T00:00:00Z | 2018-01-15T01:00:00Z |
|  3 |   Asia/Hong_Kong | 2018-01-15T00:00:00Z | 2018-01-15T08:00:00Z |
|  1 | Pacific/Auckland | 2018-01-15T00:01:00Z | 2018-01-15T13:01:00Z |
|  2 |     Europe/Paris | 2018-01-15T00:01:00Z | 2018-01-15T01:01:00Z |
|  3 |   Asia/Hong_Kong | 2018-01-15T00:01:00Z | 2018-01-15T08:01:00Z |
|  1 | Pacific/Auckland | 2018-01-15T00:02:00Z | 2018-01-15T13:02:00Z |
|  2 |     Europe/Paris | 2018-01-15T00:02:00Z | 2018-01-15T01:02:00Z |
|  3 |   Asia/Hong_Kong | 2018-01-15T00:02:00Z | 2018-01-15T08:02:00Z |
|  1 | Pacific/Auckland | 2018-01-15T00:03:00Z | 2018-01-15T13:03:00Z |
```

Comment: This is pretty unclear. What data type is `date_lib`? What is the setting of `TimeZone` when you run the query? What is the output you would expect?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Check the sqlfidle; date_lib is a `date` field with `'2018-01-15'`; the timezone of the server is `'Europe/Paris'` as I've set on the fiddle; the expected output is the last table : every GMT minute and their corresponding local time.

Comment: The result in the sqlfiddle looks right, because your time zone is set to UTC. What is your problem?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe not the last Fiddle that work but explicitly use a solution I can't use (changing the server TZ to GMT). The first one : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8fcca/2 there you'll see for Paris the GMT at 00:00 give a local of 00:00 which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing the solution is to use `timestamp without time zone` throughout:

```
SELECT to_do.id,
       to_do.tz_lib,
       seq.seq AS date_gmt,
       seq.seq AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE to_do.tz_lib AS date_local
FROM to_do
   CROSS JOIN date_needed
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      generate_series(
         date_needed.date_lib::timestamp,
         date_needed.date_lib::timestamp + INTERVAL '1439 minutes',
         INTERVAL '1 minute'
      ) seq;
```

Explanation: `seq` will deliver the UTC timestamps. By using `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`, I convert it to `timestamp with time zone` properly, and with the second `AT TIME ZONE` I see what the clock in that time zone shows at that time.

Comment: Wait What, this seem to work o_O ; I'm pretty sure I've already tried the `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE tz_lib` without any success, could you explain why this one work ? The more I dig, the less I understand pg TZ handling... (+1 for now, and I'll validate if this work in my real case)

Comment: I have added an explanation.

Comment: Ok, in fact I was really close as just adding the **`at time zone 'GMT'`** in `(date_lib + (seq ||'minute')::interval) at time zone 'GMT' at time zone tz_lib AS date_local` give me the good result... After some thinking on my problem, I was after *every minutes in local time and their corresponding GMT* but I manage to change your query to produce the expected result, So answer check for me, thanks a lot ;)